# value of variable not changing after update

Tags: javascript

I have the following code :

```
function change(initial) {
  let a = initial;
  console.log(a);
  return [
    a,
    (v) => {
      a = v;
    }
  ];
}

const [val, setter] = change("initial");

console.log(val);
setter("s");
console.log(val);
```

Val is staying the same eventhough setter has been called.
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-sun-ewqts?file=/src/index.js:0-212

If i change the return statement to this instead :

```
  return [
    () => a,
    (v) => {
      a = v;
    }
  ];
```

and then call val() as a function it works. But i want to understand why this is.

Comment: You’re updating `a` in the setter, not `val`. There is no link between the two.

Comment: `val` is a copy of the value of `a`, it's not a reference to the variable.

Comment: So if i make val a function it will have a reference to variable a when called? How does it work when its a function @Barmar

Comment: @Kevin.a The value is irrelevant. When updating a variable, it would only change a different variable if both variables are the same _reference_. This is not possible with variables in JS. Also, changing `val` is impossible anyway, because it’s `const`. You could try this with object properties, which do contain references.

Comment: @Kevin.a When it's a function, you've created a closure, and it keeps a reference to its variable environment. The  getter and setter are both closing over the same environment.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `a = "initial"; val = a; a = "s";` You wouldn't expect `val` to change, would you?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening:

1. Function is called with initial value "initial"
2. Initial value is saved as "a"
3. Array is returned with the ***current*** value of "a": "initial"
4. Setter function is called and the value of "a" is changed inside the function
5. Array value stays the same because values are not linked

How about something like this:

```js
function change(initial) {
  console.log(initial);
  return {
    get value() {
      return initial;
    },
    set value(v) {
      return initial = v;
    },
    setter: function(v) {
      return initial = v;
    }
  };
}

const obj = change("initial");

const { setter } = obj;

console.log(obj.value);
//initial
setter("s");
console.log(obj.value);
//s
obj.value = "val";
console.log(obj.value);
//val
```